# Creating a class to calculate area of a circle using Point class in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to creates a class `Circle` that calculates area of a circle.  It uses a basic Point class that initializes 2 points, one as the center one as a point on the circle (aka radius) these are the errors I am getting:

```
(25) error C2533: 'Circle::{ctor}' : constructors not allowed a return type
(25) error C2511: 'Circle::Circle(Point &,Point &)' : overloaded member function not found in 'Circle'
(12) : see declaration of 'Circle'
(46): fatal error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found
```

Maybe I have been staring at if for too long but any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "Point.h"

class Circle
{
   public:
  Circle(const Point &, const Point &);
  float getArea() const;

   private:
  Point pCenter;
  Point p1;
  float areaOfCircle;
}

Circle::Circle(Point &pointC, Point &point1)
: pCenter(pointC), p1(point1)
{

}

float Circle::getArea() const
{
areaOfCircle = 3.14159 * pow(pCenter.distanceTo(p1),2);
return areaOfCircle;
}

int main()
{
Point pointCenter

cout << "The center point is at: " //pointCenter.getX() << ","  
    << pointCenter.getY() << endl;
cout << "A point on the circle is at: " //pointRadius.getX() << "," 
    << pointRadius.getY() << endl;

    cin.ignore(2);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of issues with this code:

- You are missing a semicolon after the class declaration.
- Missing semicolon after pointCenter declaration.
- Missing pointRadius declaration
- Missing "using namespace std"
- two different function interfaces for the constructor (with and without const)
- areaOfCircle cannot be modified in a const function

Fixing the above issues will make the code compile (but there is more to be solved after that).

Answer (score 1):

You declared your constructor to take

```
class Circle {
    ...
    Circle(Point const&, Point const&);
    ...
};
```

but you defined it to take non-`const` references:

```
Circle::Circle(Point&, Point&) {
     ...
}
```

That's not going to work.

BTW, if you want to compute the square of a value, you are a lot better off using `x * x` than `std::exp(x, 2)`! The latter function is fairly involved and generally not as fast.